# C++ Struct vector, Junk string value

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Now I'm studying vector of structs, and attempt to print it after sorting by ppid. In this process, I want to test "'the string value' is saved well", but some junk value is saved this space like below picture.

[image]

:: Second value **"contest.exe" is saved well,**

::but, as you see, the first value **"Microsoft.VsHub~" is saved like "?(triangle)"**

Why this problem occured, and how to solved it?

This is my structure,

```
struct process {
    string procName;
    DWORD procPid;
    DWORD procPpid;
};

main(){
    ...
    std::vector <process*> myProcess;
    ...
}
```

Save value like,

```
    process* p = new process();
    p->procName = pe32.szExeFile;
    p->procPid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
    p->procPpid = pe32.th32ParentProcessID;

    myProcess.push_back(p);
```

and print this

```
    _tprintf(TEXT("[%s]"), pe32.szExeFile);
    _tprintf(TEXT(" %s \n"), myProcess[i]);
    _tprintf(TEXT("[%d]"), myProcess[i]->procPid);
```

Comment: In general, avoid naked pointers in STL containers, use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Is `string` a `std::string`?

Comment: In general, avoid pointers where possible. Store elements by value (`std::vector<process>`) instead.

Comment: @Pixelchemist - pointers are core to the language and having _referring-only_ pointers in a vector is no problem. It's when they the vector has _ownership_ of the pointers that issues tend to stack up. Then use whole objects/values if possible and smart pointers otherwise, the type of which should be determined by the sharing needs.

Comment: @JohannGerell: Non-ownership is when storage by value is not suitable but the code that is part of the question indicates that storing by value is probably the best choice here. Not only because a vector of values is more versatile (elements copyable, moveable, ...) but also because of performance considerations (adjacent storage, cache effects, ...) My recommendation holds. For ownership: `value > smart pointer > pointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
_tprintf(TEXT(" %s \n"), myProcess[i]);
```

you try to print the content of the `process*` in the `myProcess` vector at index `i` **as a null terminated string**. Try `myProcess[i]->procName.c_str()` instead.

Comment: Time limit will be end soon :)